# Is java client of PAHO proxy aware and enables sending of MQTT messages across enterprise proxy to brokers hosted in the internet?

Tags: java, proxy, mqtt, paho

Organization provides http proxy and https proxy.

If not within enterprise network successfully establishing a secure connection (ssl://brokerhost:brokerport)

1.Passing relevant keystore and truststore

2.Setting default instance of SSLSocketFactory in MqttConnectOptions.

Comment: Do you mean native MQTT or MQTT over websockets?

Comment: Also it's not clear what you mean in the second half of your question, are you asking how to create a SSL connection?

Comment: I meant native MQTT.In second half I was merely documenting the steps which I used to establish SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

No, for native MQTT there is no way to use a HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

You can not use a HTTP proxy to transport an arbitrary TCP based protocol. You need something like [SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) (ssh can be used to to setup socks proxies or to do port forwarding to remote [not the ssh host] location)

Comment: okay so additional SOCKS based proxy needs to be present.If at all MQTT traffic needs to be send through proxy IP.

Comment: I suggest you do some research about using socks proxies with Java. There is at least one SocksSocketFactory implmentation