# How do I send MQTT over websocket w/ paho when I have an HTTP proxy? (java client)

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I am trying to connect to an external endpoint, but traffic to external endpoints has to be forwarded through an http proxy. How do I do this in the paho Java client? I can't find their Authenticator/know what to set to make this work. You can set custom headers but I don't know how to make that work with a proxy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is java client of PAHO proxy aware and enables sending of MQTT messages across enterprise proxy to brokers hosted in the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253083/is-java-client-of-paho-proxy-aware-and-enables-sending-of-mqtt-messages-across-e)

Comment: added details. that person was asking for pure mqtt, not mqtt over websockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/tree/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/websocket) I'm not sure you can out of the box at the moment.

This [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/419) includes a code to use a Custom SocketFactory to make a connection via a proxy. (This might work if you don't need to authenticate to use your proxy)

And there is an open feature request [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/575) to add it to the core code.